# Memcache control panel?

Tags: caching, memcached, controlpanel, eaccelerator

We've been running [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/) on each of 3 webservers and are looking to move to a [memcache](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) pool across all 3, hopefully reducing by about 2/3 our db lookups.

One of the handy things about eAccelerator is the web-based control interface ([control.php](http://eaccelerator.net/browser/eaccelerator/tags/0.9.5-rc1/control.php)), which has proved very useful when we've had to flush the cache unexpectedly, quickly monitor which scripts are in cache, etc.

We've been looking but haven't found anything that offers the same type of functionality for memcache - does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Obviously flushing cache etc is easy enough with memcache on the console, but our particular set-up means we may have guys monitoring our front-end and needing to flush the cache who will not necessarily have shell access on the servers.

Comment: http://articles.digitalpoint.com/content.php?r=14-Monitor-Memcached-Servers-With-vBulletin
http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[memcache.php](http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/) may be what you're looking for.

> memcache.php that you can get stats and dump from multiple memcache servers.

Can [delete keys](http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/07/30/memcachephp-can-delete-keys-now/) and [flush servers](http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/08/28/memcachephp-flushes-servers/).

Comment: it's also now included in the APC distribution package from PECL.

Comment: by the APC package, I do of course, mean the memcache PECL package.

Comment: The link to memcache.php in the answer is broken. Alternatively there is phpMemcachedAdmin which I've forked onto Github and added some new features such as live charts for monitoring Memcached in real time: https://github.com/kevin-jones/phpMemcachedAdmin

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a late addition to an old question but none of the answers were a simple plain solution, so i created one and put it up on [`github`](https://github.com/bainternet/Memchaced-Dashboard) for you to enjoy:

### Screenshoots

[image: Login]
[image: server info]
[image: Some charts]
[image: Stored keys]

Comment: Thanks. Best interface for managing memcached that I've seen so far. I hope you continue to improve on this, such as refreshing individual keys and using AJAX when deleting keys so the entire interface doesn't have to reload. :)

Comment: @RyanH. if you have suggestions please feel free to open an issue on github and I'll find the time to update and implement.

Answer (score 2):

PHPMemcacheAdmin - http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

Answer (score 0):

> If all you need to do is to be able to flush the cache from a web-application, you could create a simple php-page and then use the system() call...

Cache flushing is part of what we're looking for, but also a way to monitor what scripts are currently in there, how much data is in there, etc - basically the same stuff available on the EA control panel page.

We've played around with munin plugins for showing data usage, and were thinking we'd have to go down the line suggested above (system calls, etc), but were hoping that someone, somewhere would have rolled something similar already!